# How do I move where Docker Images are stored under Windows 2016

Tags: windows, docker, windows-server-2016

I've automated creation of VMs for my developers, and I want to distribute this base image, and script the creation of the secondary drive to as large as they want for container storage.

I can't figure out how to change the default docker image folder from the C: drive to the E: Data drive.

Hopefully someone has already figured this one out and can point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Used the correct google search terms and found the answer myself: [Docker Engine On Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/manage-docker/configure-docker-daemon).

Create a file daemon.json and put it in installation folder. Example: C:\ProgramData\docker\config\daemon.json

Inside that file use the graph keyword

```
{
    "graph": "e:\\docker_containers"
}
```

Please note that you must have an extra CRLF added to the end of this file, or when you start the service it will crash with its parser.